# Bandwidth: voltage-source vs. current-source gate drivers

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, semiconductors, gate-driving, powermosfet

Why do voltage-source gate drivers provide low-to-medium bandwidth that does not work well for wide band gap devices, while current-source gate drivers provide hundreds of MHz of bandwidth?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Examples of each?

Comment: In your question you refer to "band gap" I think you may mean "bandwidth". Band gap means something completely different to bandwidth, and doesn't seem related to your question.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I think the OP is referring to GaN or SiC FETs, which are wide-bandgap semiconductors.

Comment: I can't see any reason for this to be true in general, so examples will be needed.

Comment: I think because voltage has to reach equilibrium with the gate capacitance - it has an exponential decay - current doesn't.